# How to avoid hitting database in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I get that one should not ping the database in the view... but wondering about the right solution. In one of my views, I need to pull info on an `@order`, it's child `items`, and also `Amount`, another model, based on each child `item`. Something like this:

```
<% @order.items.each do |item| %>
  <td><%= item.name %></td>
  <td><%= Refund.where(item_id:item.id).first.amount %></td>
  <td><%= Amount.where(item_id: item.id).first.amount %></td>
<% end %>
```

For the sake of avoiding the db hits in the view, the only solution I've thought of is to create a huge hash of all the relevant data in the controller, which is then accessed from the view. So it would be something like this:

```
# controller (writing quickly, code may not be totally right, hopefully you get gist
data = Hash.new
data["items"] = []
@order.items.each do |item|
  item_hash = {
    "name" => item.name,
    "amount" => Amount.where(item_id: item.id).first.amount,
    "refund" => Refund.where(item_id:item.id).first.amount
  }
  data["items"] << item_hash
end

# view code
<% data["items"].each do |item| %>
  <td><%= item["name"] %></td>
  <td><%= item["refund"] %></td>
  <td><%= item["amount"] %></td>
<% end %>
```

And I know SO hates this type of question... but I really need to know... is that the best solution? Or are there are best practices? The reason I ask is because it seems very clean in the view, but very bulky in the controller, and also it gets quite unwieldy when you have a much more complex set of nested tables, which is what I actually have (i.e., the `data` hash would be quite funky to put together)

Comment: Remember `{}` is as good as `Hash.new` and a lot more concise.

Comment: What is the association between item, refund, and amount? one to one, one to many? i.e. item has_one :refund ? Your question indicates item potentially has many refunds, but my question is if this is your intent?

Answer (score 5):

First of I would use associations between item and the 2 other classes, so that you can do

```
item.refund
item.amount
```

Instead of `Refund.where(...)`. You could further define methods such as

```
def refund_amount
  refund.amount
end
```

And similarly for the other one (and hopefully come up with a better name than `amount_amount`.

This keeps both your view and controller clean but it won't be any faster. So far all of the approaches involve running 2 database queries per item which is the real issue as far as I'm concerned - whether those excess queries happen in the view or the controller is of lesser concern.

However you can avoid this with Active Record's include mechanism:

```
Item.include(:amount,:refund).where("your conditions here")
```

Will load the named associations in bulk rather than loaded them one at a time as each item is accessed.

Comment: yes sorry, i asked this question late at night so that was silly, the associations ARE in place, so I can just do an `item.refund`. I see what you're saying, thanks for the reminder on using `include`. I will keep the view only approach, thanks!